# Stop function when document clicked

Tags: jquery, function

I am trying to stop a function I named `defaultState` when the document is clicked but I used `stop();`, `stop(true, true);`, `stopPropagation();` and more but couldn't stop the animation from happening...It's obvious I'm doing something wrong..but what?

**JS** ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv1ow2q9/1/))

```
function defaultState(){
    $('#me').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            'background-color': '#339966'
        },300);
    },function(){
        $(this).animate({
            'background-color': 'red'
        },300);
    });
};

defaultState();

$(document).click(function(){
    defaultState.stop(true, true);
});
```

Comment: `defaultState` is a custom function, it cannot be stopped. But you want to stop the animation? (which only takes 300ms?)

Comment: Where did you see that `defaultState.stop(true, true);` is supposed to do something? You should read some beginner level tutorials on: JavaScript, jQuery, jQuery animations. Then try again

Comment: @Amit You are right...I got so caught up with stopping events that I started wanting to stop functions the same way :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, what you mean, is that you want to stop any future animations from happening and stop any animation happening right now, then you can call `.stop()` and then remove the event handler that `defaultState()` installed with:

```
$("#me").stop(true).off();
```

Or, you can target only the `.hover()` mouse event handlers with this:

```
$("#me").stop(true).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Comment: Thank you, I got all mixed up from stopping events to stopping functions..the second one is the one for me :)

Comment: You are right when saying I don't want only to stop an animation of 300ms, this is a looot more complex but I only made that as an isolated example instead of posting 2 pages of code...I got so caught up with stopping events that I started wanting to stop functions the same way :))

Answer (score 3):

You need to call stop method on animated element and not on your function which doesn't have such method.

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('#me').stop();
});
```

try it here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q33b6235/)

Comment: It seems unlikely that the only thing the OP is trying to do is to stop a 300ms animation in progress.